# Conserved Charge in Conformal Field Theory

Tags: conservation-laws, conformal-field-theory

I am reading *Introduction to Conformal Field Theory* by Blumenhagen and Plauschinn, and do not quite understand how eq. 2.33 for the conserved charge

$$
Q = \int dx^1 j_0
$$

is converted to eq. 2.34:

$$
Q = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \left(
    dz \, \epsilon(z) T(z)
    + d\bar{z} \, \bar{\epsilon}(\bar{z}) \bar{T}(\bar{z})
\right)
$$

where $z, \bar{z}$ are related to the original $x^0, x^1$ coordinates by eq. 2.23:

$$
z = e^{x^0 + ix^1}, \quad \bar{z} = e^{x^0 - ix^1}
$$

I am aware of [another Physics SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164278/222821), but the answers there is not clear enough for me. Below is my attempt (some steps are from [Schellekens' CFT lecture notes](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Et58/CFT.pdf)): in 2D CFT, one originally goes from the real plane to the complex coordinates $z, \bar{z}$ by

$$
z = x^0 + ix^1, \quad
\bar{z} = x^0 - ix^1
$$

and the conserved current is given by eq. 2.19

$$
j_\mu = T_{\mu \nu} \epsilon^\nu
$$

where $T_{\mu \nu}$ is the energy-momentum tensor, and $\epsilon^\nu$ is the infinitesimal conformal coordinate transformation (eq. 2.2). Using the transformation laws for tensors and vectors under coordinate transformation ($z^0, z^1 = z, \bar{z}$)

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \text{Vector: } &\quad &
    j_\mu(z) &= \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial z^\mu} j_\nu(x)
    \\
    \text{Tensor: } &\quad &
    T_{\mu \nu} (z) &= \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial z^\mu}
    \frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial z^\nu}
    T_{\rho \sigma}(x)
\end{aligned}
$$

One arrives at

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \epsilon_z \\ \epsilon_{\bar{z}}
    \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_0 - i \epsilon_1) \\
        \frac{1}{2}(\epsilon_0 + i \epsilon_1)
    \end{pmatrix}
    \\
    \begin{pmatrix}
        j_z \\ j_{\bar{z}}
    \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{1}{2}(j_0 - i j_1) \\
        \frac{1}{2}(j_0 + i j_1)
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        2 T_{zz} \epsilon_{\bar{z}} \\
        2 T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}} \epsilon_z
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

One usually adopts the definition (eq. 5.40 in the Francesco et al Yellow Book, but with minus sign removed to match Blumenhagen's convention)

$$
T(z) = 2\pi T_{zz}(z), \quad
\bar{T}(\bar{z}) = 2\pi T_{\bar{z}\bar{z}}(\bar{z})
$$

and (the eq below eq. 2.10; we are in Euclidean space, so upper and lower indices are the same)

$$
\epsilon(z) = \epsilon_0 + i\epsilon_1, \quad
\bar{\epsilon}(\bar{z}) = \epsilon_0 - i\epsilon_1
$$

Then

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    j_z \\ j_{\bar{z}}
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \begin{pmatrix}
    T(z) \epsilon(z) \\
    \bar{T}(\bar{z}) \bar{\epsilon}(\bar{z})
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I emphasize that this $z, \bar{z}$ is the usual complexified coordinates, not the $e^{x^0 \pm ix^1}$ used in radial quantization. Next we perform this further conformal transformation of coordinates

$$
\begin{aligned}
    w &= e^z = e^{x^0 + ix^1} \\
    \bar{w} &= e^{\bar{z}} = e^{x^0 - ix^1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then the current is transformed to (using the inverse $z = \ln{w}, \bar{z} = \ln{\bar{w}}$ and the vector transformation rule)

$$
\begin{aligned}
    j_w(w) = \frac{1}{w} j_z(z) \\
    j_{\bar{w}}(\bar{w}) = \frac{1}{\bar{w}} 
    j_{\bar{z}}(\bar{z})
\end{aligned}
$$

With periodic boundary condition on $x^1$ (I choose the radius of the cylinder to be 1)

$$
\phi(x^1) = \phi(x^1 + 2\pi N), \quad N \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

the expression for the current becomes

$$
Q = \int_0^{2\pi} dx^1 j^0
$$

First, the current $j^0$ is decoupled into a chiral part and an anti-chiral part:

$$
\begin{aligned}
    j^0 &= j_z(z) + j_{\bar{z}}(\bar{z})
    \\
    &= w j_w(w) + \bar{w} j_{\bar{w}}(\bar{w})
\end{aligned}
$$

With radial quantization, constant $x^1$ lines is mapped to a circle centered at the origin with radius $\exp{x^0} = 1$ (one usually choose $x^0 = 0$ since $Q$ is conserved). Then we transform the integration over $x^1$ as follows:

- For the first term depending on $w$:

  $$
  \int_0^{2\pi} dx^1 
  \to \frac{1}{i} \oint_0 \frac{1}{w} dw 
  \quad (w = e^{ix^1})
  $$
- For the second term depending on $\bar{w}$, we have a similar expression:

  $$
  \begin{aligned}
      \int_0^{2\pi} dx^1 
      &\to \frac{1}{-i} \oint_{0,\text{cw}} 
      \frac{1}{\bar{w}} d\bar{w} 
      \\
      &= \frac{1}{i} \oint_0 \frac{1}{\bar{w}} d\bar{w} 
      \quad (\bar{w} = e^{-ix^1}) 
  \end{aligned}
  $$

  where the extra minus sign changed the clockwise (cw) integration to a counter-clockwise one.

Then we arrive at

$$
Q = \frac{1}{i} \oint dw \, j_w(w)
+ \frac{1}{i} \oint d\bar{w} \,
j_{\bar{w}} (\bar{w})
$$

This is very close to the final answer eq. 2.34. However, this $w$ is not the same as $z$, and the expressions

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
j_z \\ j_{\bar{z}}
\end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \begin{pmatrix}
T(z) \epsilon(z) \\
\bar{T}(\bar{z}) \bar{\epsilon}(\bar{z})
\end{pmatrix}
$$

cannot be directly plug in the $Q$ above. What further steps are needed?

Comment: I think you're confusing the plane and cylinder. Then people write the first expression you've written down as a $z$-integral, it is an integral over a loop in the plane. At the end of the day though, the integral for $Q$ is always an integral along some curve, it's just that this only has a nice standard meaning as a contour integral to which Cauchy's theorems can be applied if we are in the plane.

Comment: I am indeed very confused about this. Why is $j_z = (1/2\pi) T(z)\epsilon(z)$ applicable to the cylinder? It is originally obtained using the old coordinate transformation $z,\bar{z} = x^0 \pm ix^1$, but now the coordinate transformation is $z, \bar{z} = e^{x^0 \pm ix^1}$, so the expression should be different.

Comment: In addition, could you please kindly help explain a statement in Schellekens' CFT lecture notes below eq. 2.3: "the integration is along a closed contour that encircles the cylinder"; there $z,\bar{z} = x^0\pm ix^1$, but I don't know how a contour in the complex plane can "encircle" a cylinder, and it seems that he is integrating along a straight line with constant $\operatorname{Im} z$. So what is the contour in this case?

Comment: For the latter, you may want to review what a circle in the plane maps to on the cylinder. For the charge, this is just the statement that the Noether charge associated to a diff is the contraction of the diff on the stress tensor.

Comment: I think you are implicitly meaning $z = e^{x^0+ix^1}$ so that a 0-centered circle on the plane will naturally encircle the cylinder. But I emphasize again that in eq. 2.3 of Schellekens **the variable $z$ is $x^0+ix^1$**; it is just like rolling a strip of plane into a cylinder. Then sorry, I am not quite clear about what you mean.

Comment: Ah, in that case I believe your difficulty lies in the definition of complex contour integrals. In the complexified coordinates, an integral over $z$ alone is, indeed, an integral over a 1-dimensional contour, not a 2d region. For instance, this can be seen by noting that $dz$ is a 1-form and hence must be integrated over a 1-dimensional submanifold of the plane (or cylinder, whatever).